# Batch attach unattached images

Tags: import

I'm making some updates + imports to my own (really old) blog. Through the years different web sites has been imported to it and many old images are in the media library but not attached to any post there. They are linked in content from blog posts.

Are there any way to search the content and attach images to the blog post where it's shown in. I think all images are only shown on one blog post.

My idea would be to filter out all media that is unattached in media library and then search all posts + pages for that file name. If found - attach it there. But if something exists I'm sure that solution would be much better :)

Thanks.

Comment: The first step is finding them. You'll basically need to work out some MySQL queries to run (on a backed-up database). Is the upload folder unique - i.e. does it only contain images that were manually uploaded and are not in the Media Library?

Comment: All files are in the upload folder. Many of them are from a flickr-to-wordpress import that I myself built a tool for some years ago before I realised that it wasnt enough to just put the files in the upload folder and then link them in a post.... (without adding them to media library)

Those files are in uploads / flickr

Comment: You can set up a couple of regexes to search `wp_posts` - `post_content` for references to images that are just in the `/uploads/` folder (not inside monthly folders like the ones in the Media Library) and references to the ones in the `/uploads/flickr/` folder. Once you've identified where they are in the posts, my suggestion would be to actually edit each post they are in, upload the file(s) to the Media Library - which if you're editing a post will attach them to that post - and delete the old ones as you go. If they're indexed you may also want to redirect them to their new URLs.

Comment: (If you don't put the images in the Media Library, you won't be able to "attach" them, because to be "attached" means they each have an entry in `wp_posts` and the `post_parent` is the post they are attached to.)

Comment: The images were in media library but not attached to any post there. Just checked. My mistake. Sorry.